# Convert dec to hex and using hex in switch C++

Tags: c++

I was given a task and I made it a little more complicated by trying to write it in C++
My assignment:
Display on the screen hexadecimal codes of characters entered from the keyboard. Use characters R, L, Q, m,p and use these codes to start an Explorer program, indicate the path to a folder, create a text file, delete a file, close the current Explorer window, respectively.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
void create_file()
{
    cout << "Enter file name: ";
    char filename[21] = { 0 };
    cin >> filename;
    strcat_s(filename, ".txt");
    FILE* file;
    fopen_s(&file, filename, "w");
    if (file != NULL)
    {
        cout << "File created\n";
            fclose(file);
    }
    else
        cout << "Error creating file\n";
}
void delete_file()
{
    cout << "Enter name deleting file: ";
    char filename[21] = { 0 };
    cin >> filename;
    if (remove(filename) != 0)
        cout << "Error deleting file" << endl;
    else
        cout << "File sucsesfull deleted" << endl;
}
void open_folder()
{
    cout << "Example folder path: D:\\Server\n";
    TCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
    cout << "Enter folder path: ";
    wcin >> path;
    try
    {
        ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", path, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
    }
    catch (exception)
    {
        cout << "Can't open folder\n";
    }
}
void symbol_output(int symb)
{
    cout.unsetf(ios::dec);
    cout.setf(ios::hex);
    cout << "Symbol " << (char)symb << ", hexadecimal: 0x";
    cout << hex << symb << endl;

}


//int convert_10_to_16(int symb) //this function does not fit here
//{
//  std::string d = "0123456789abcd";

//  int num = symb;
//  std::string res;
//
//  while (num > 0)
//  {
//      res = d[num % 16] + res;
//      num /= 16;
//  }

    std::cout << res << std::endl;

    return num;
}

void close_window()
{
    HWND hwnd;
    hwnd = FindWindow(L"CabinetWClass", NULL);
    if (hwnd != NULL)
        SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0);
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    int symb;
    cout << " R - Open explorer\n L - Open folder\n Q - Creating text file\n m - Deleting text file\n p - Close the current explorer window\n";
    cout << "Input e for exit" << endl;

    do
    {
        cout << "Input Symbol: ";
        symb = _getch();
        symbol_output(symb);
        symb = convert_10_to_16(symb);
        
        switch (symb)
        {
        case 0x52: // R
            ShellExecuteA(0, "open", "Explorer", NULL, NULL, SW_RESTORE);
            break;
        case 0x4c: // L
            open_folder();
            break;
        case 0x51: // Q
            create_file();
            break;
        case 0x6d: // m
            delete_file();
            break;
        case 0x70: // p
            close_window();
            break;
        }
    } while (symb != 0x65); // e
}
```

int convert_10_to_16(int symb) this function is absolutely incorrect.

Be kind enough to point out my mistakes, back it up with your arguments or references such as why it should or should not be done.
Also, is there a hex type in C++ and can it be passed to Switch or do I have to use another option?
I tried to pass code without 0x in int format, but two letters include a number and a letter.
Frankly, I'm completely confused.

Comment: Hello! Can you please provide a more concise explanation of the problem you are seeking help on? Here is some documentation on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Using the "0x" before your hex will tell the compiler to create an int with that hexcode. Therefore, your switch statement would work without using convert_10_to_16 at all because the compiler is already making the conversion for your hexcodes.

```
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    int symb;
    cout << " R - Open explorer\n L - Open folder\n Q - Creating text file\n m - Deleting text file\n p - Close the current explorer window\n";
    cout << "Input e for exit" << endl;

    do
    {
        cout << "Input Symbol: ";
        symb = _getch();
        symbol_output(symb);
        
        switch (symb)
        {
        case 0x52: // R
            ShellExecuteA(0, "open", "Explorer", NULL, NULL, SW_RESTORE);
            break;
        case 0x4c: // L
            open_folder();
            break;
        case 0x51: // Q
            create_file();
            break;
        case 0x6d: // m
            delete_file();
            break;
        case 0x70: // p
            close_window();
            break;
        }
    } while (symb != 0x65); // e
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't seen this it's help me.

Comment: FYI: This is just a stupid way of writing `case 'R':` and so on.